# i want to match only start tags in regex

Tags: c#, .net, html, regex, tags

i am making a regex expression in which i want to only match wrong tags like

`<p> *some text here, some other tags may be here as well but no ending 'p' tag* </p>`

```
 <P>Affectionately Inscribed </P><P>TO </P><P>HENRY BULLAR, </P><P>(of the western circuit)<P>PREFACE</P>
```

like in the above same text i want to get the result as  `<P>(of the western circuit)<P>` and nothing else should be captured. im using this but its not working

```
<P>[^\(</P>\)]*<P>
```

please help

Comment: Duplicate of this [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/577210/i-want-to-match-only-start-tags-in-regex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/577210/i-want-to-match-only-start-tags-in-regex)

Comment: Please continue the existing thread; don't open duplicates.

Comment: @MarcGravell: Close this please.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an expression that will match what you need:

```
[<]{1}\s*[pP]{1}\s*[>]{1}[()a-zA-Z0-9 ]+[<]{1}\s*[pP]{1}\s*[>]{1}
```

You can add to this all chars you need [()a-zA-Z0-9 ].